Methods to backup files to desktop

Say I have Android 10+. (This means phone is encrypted with FBE?)
I am using internal storage

I want to copy files to my desktop.

I just need USB cable and choose use it for File Transfer.
On Windows I could use quick share?

These are the only two methods not using intermediaries (Google photos, Dropbox)
Would this methods work as well if I install SD Card?

USB File Transfer (MTP) works for accessing shared storage. However MTP is known to be slow and not very reliable. If you are not afraid of command-line I would recommend enabling developer options and ADB on the phone and install minimal-adb on PC side and then copy files via adb pull from phone.

afair android 10 has no restrictions on copying MicroSD Card
